# Proof of accommodation when renting a flat unofficially?

Tags: schengen, netherlands, proof-of-accommodation

I need a short-stay Schengen visa to The Netherlands for study purposes (2-month internship). The university is *not* providing me accommodation, and I'm looking for accommodation on several housing groups, where people sub-let their rented rooms when they are away, etc. So it's quite an informal agreement, and no paperwork goes into subletting for such short durations.

How do I give a proof of accommodation in such a case? Will a signed letter from the tenant stating it all work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Considering the informal landlord will probably be avoiding tax on your rent... You really wouldn't want to give *that* impression to the authorities.

Comment: The question is about a short-stay visa. I really don't think we should be closing it as an off-topic expats question: the answer would surely be identical if the asker wanted to take a two-month holiday in the Netherlands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and no paperwork goes into subletting for such short durations

Why not? In the Netherlands, it is completely normal to set up a basic contract even for short stay subletting. There is no harm in asking for a simple contract you and the 'landlord' (i.e., current tenant) can sign. There are only benefits to having a piece of paper proving that you're allowed to stay there. Since Dutch law provides extensive protections for tenants, the contract does not need to be complicated (there's plenty of templates for your landlord to choose from online). Usually, the contract just states what you're renting (something like "a single room, and use of the common areas including the washing machine"), for how long (start and end date) and how much to pay each month to whom.

By the way, just because the university doesn't provide you with housing, does not mean you can't use housing aimed at foreign students. Most cities with a university have a building cooperation aimed at student housing which generally also provides short stay housing. There may also be other commercial alternatives like student hotels.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm in the Netherlands now (Delft to be precise), and my experience is that short-term student housing is practically nonexistent with any housing/rental company, leaving these informal housing groups as the only option. There's one student hostel, but it works out more expensive. But that's only Delft, and I'm told other cities don't have this housing shortage.
Your clarification that "any simple contract signed by the current tenant will do" is correct and helpful, that's exactly what the immigration officials needed.

Answer (score -2):

No, when you register yourself at any address at the council in the Gemeentelijke Basis Administratie (GBA), you will need a buyer's agreement or rent agreement. If you have neither you will need authorization by the official owner/rentee. [Here](http://decentrale.regelgeving.overheid.nl/cvdr/xhtmloutput/Historie/Utrecht%20(Utr)/CVDR46071/CVDR46071_1.html) is some information in a related document.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand what you mean by *authorization by official rentee*. How can the rentee give me that or what is that document commonly called?

Comment: @QMrules it's the permission from the landlord.

Comment: Tourists don't need to register anywhere when arriving to the Netherlands. You are talking about long term visas.

Comment: As I understood the question it's not a tourist, but someone living there hence the requirement to register at the GBA